# Pressing 'Tab' will move certain bones slightly

Tags: rigging, armature, edit-mode, pose-mode

I know that pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> does not change the position of the skeleton in edit mode and pose mode.

When I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the skeleton of hand are moves a little strangely.Other bones do not move.

What causes this problem?

Here's a video that shows the problem: https://youtu.be/BGQlwQkXdns

Here's the *.blend* file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ji4xjti2umhoxcd/2b_08_middle%20of%20additory%20bones.blend?dl=0

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a IK-solver applied on some bones. This constrain does not work in edit mode, so when you go to object/pose mode, constrain starts to affect and moves bones a little.

Other thing that you show in video - it is bone in the head, it is hidden in edit mode, so you need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show it.

And by the way, do you know that rigify addon, that you use, has a Rig generator, witch builds all logic for you and you need not to add constraints and additional bones manually?

[image]

Comment: Thanks Crantisz. I know I need not to add constraint if i Generate rig. But after this way. The pole doesn't work. I don't know why. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121180/after-generate-rig-the-pole-doesnt-work-why