# After Generate rig, the pole doesn't work. why?

Tags: rigging

After Generate rig.

Press Alt+H to find pole. 
Click the Pole and moves sideways.

But the knee does not work... why?

Here's a video that shows the problem: https://youtu.be/24uUGUPolzc

Here's the .blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bt614qj16vdnsjt/2b_07.blend?dl=0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Blenrig has 2 variants of manipulation pole rotation. First is a rotation bone itself (two arrow bone), next is a pole target, witch is hidden by script. And the reason that script always hides the pole target is because it does not use.

There is a switcher between bone rotation and pole target rotation is in <kbd>N</kbd>-panel has name **pole_vector**:

[image]

when it sets to 1, bone rotation disables, and pole target shows.

To find this switch select **Foot_IK** bone.